# PCB Single 90 Degree Connectors for More Secure and Removable Connection

Tags: pcb, connector

I am building lithium battery packs and want to connect the power lines securely to each pad on the printed circuit board of the battery monitoring system (BMS) board. I am using braided wires with silicon sheathing to connect to each pad.

The wires need to be removable so that field servicing the batteries is possible without the need to solder/unsolder each wire.

I'd like suggestions on possible connector solutions - I've been digging through Digikey but no joy. Here are views of the BMS card. Thanks!

[image: BMS Board Bottom View]

[image: BMS Board Top View]

Comment: Do you know how much current is expected through the connectors?

Comment: I would expect up to 40 Amps from the main power connectors & significantly less from the others as I assume they're mainly for monitoring battery voltages but I could definitely be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

How about a ring crimp connector?

Nice and robust and, properly screwed on, won't come off.  Or perhaps a spade connector.  Pictures at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimp_(electrical)).  Long catalogue at [TE](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=82004_FASTON_TERMINALS_-_FULL_CATALOG&DocType=CS&DocLang=EN)

Comment: The issue is how to mechanically connect it to the PCB. - Possibly this? https://media.digikey.com/Photos/Keystone%20Elect%20Photos/MFG_1537.jpg
https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/keystone-electronics/1537/36-1537-ND/315509

Comment: @cpuguru a regular bolt (or machine screw) and nut could work fine. Use a small washer to ensure contact with the board. It’s hard to tell how large the holes are, but a M3 bolt would be quite sturdy.

Comment: @cpuguru ... perhaps a screw through and a washer?  NB 40A is a lot for a small board and small connectors, how long and fat are the cables?